# Bop it Arduino Circuit Playground

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to create a bop it game with 2 players where:
Green LED – Gyro Sensor (Z-axis)
Red LED – Temperature sensor
Blue LED – Sound sensor
Yellow LED – Light Sensor
However when I press the left button to start the game, only the yellow light above GND goes on and doesn't respond to anything, what can be wrong with my code?

```
long randNumber;
int temp;
int val;
int number;
int score;
boolean state;
int light;
uint8_t pixeln = 0;
int sound;
int shake;
unsigned long lastmillis = 0;
boolean game;
const byte numPins = 7;
byte pins[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};


int player1 = 0;
int player2 = 0;
#include "Adafruit_CircuitPlayground.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
CircuitPlayground.begin();
CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
//timer();

}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(4) == HIGH && digitalRead(19) == LOW){
    Serial.println("Button Pressed");  
    lastmillis = millis();
  
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i  ){
      randNumber = random(4);
      //Serial.println("Loop");
 

      switch (randNumber){
        //Serial.println("Switch");
        case 0:
          while (pixeln < 10){
            CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pixeln  , 255,0,0);
            CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
          }
          pixeln = 0;
          state = true;
          temp = analogRead(A0);
      //Serial.println(temp);
          while (state == true) {
            val = analogRead(A0);
            number = val - temp;
            if (number > 10){
              score  ;
              state = false;
          //Serial.println("Temperature");
              delay(500);
            }
        
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          while (pixeln < 10){
            CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pixeln  , 127,127,0);
            CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
           }
          pixeln = 0;
          state = true;
          light = analogRead(A5);
        //Serial.println(light);
          while (state == true) {
            val = analogRead(A5);
            number = light - val;
            if (number > 20){
              score  ;
              state = false;
              //Serial.println(number);
              delay(500);
            }
     
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          while (pixeln < 10){
            CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pixeln  , 0,0,255);
            CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
          }
          pixeln = 0;
          state = true;
          sound = analogRead(A4);
          //Serial.println(sound);
          while (state == true) {
            val = analogRead(A4);
            number = val - sound;
            if (number > 50){
              score  ;
              state = false;
              //Serial.println(number);
              delay(500);
          }
        
        }
          break;
        case 3:
          while (pixeln < 10){
          CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pixeln  , 0,255,0);
          CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
        
          }
          pixeln = 0;
        
          val = CircuitPlayground.motionZ();
          //Serial.println(val);
          state = true;
          while (state == true) {
            shake = CircuitPlayground.motionZ();
            number = val - shake;
          //Serial.println(number);
            if (number > 15 or number < -15){
              score  ;
              state = false;
            //Serial.println("shake");
              delay(500);
            }
        
          }
          break;
         case 4:
             CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0, 0,255,0);
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1, 0,255,0);
             CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
             delay(3000);
      
          break;       
         case 5:
             CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3, 255,0,0);
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4, 255,0,0);
             CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
             delay(3000);
          break;       
         case 6:
             CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5, 127,0,255);
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6, 127,0,255);
             CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
             delay(3000);
          break;       
         case 7:
             CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8, 255,128,0);
             CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9, 255,128,0);
             CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
             delay(3000);
      
      }
    }
  if (CircuitPlayground.slideSwitch()) {
    player1 = (millis() - lastmillis) / 1000;
    Serial.println(player1);
    CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
    byte num = player1;
    for (byte i=0; i < numPins; i  ){
      byte state = bitRead(num, i);
      if (state == 1){
        CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pins[i], 255,255,255);
        CircuitPlayground.strip.show(); 
      }
     
    }
  } else {
    player2 = (millis() - lastmillis) /1000;
    
    Serial.println(player2);
    CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
    byte num = player2;
    for (byte i=0; i < numPins; i  ){
      byte state = bitRead(num, i);
      if (state == 1){
        CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(pins[i], 255,255,255);
        CircuitPlayground.strip.show(); 
      }
    }}
CircuitPlayground.playTone(330, 500);
  }
while (digitalRead(19) == HIGH && digitalRead(4) == LOW){  
        if (player1 < player2){
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels(); 
          delay(250);
          for (int i =0; i < 5; i  ){
          CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(i, 255,255,255);
          CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
          }
          delay(250);
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
        }
        else if (player1 > player2){
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels(); 
          delay(250);
          for (int i =5; i < 10; i  ){
          CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(i, 255,255,255);
          CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
          }
          delay(250);
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
        }
        else {
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels(); 
          delay(250);
          for (int i =0; i < 10; i  ){
          CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(i, 255,255,255);
          CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
          }
          delay(250);
          CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
        }
  }
if (digitalRead(19) == HIGH && digitalRead(4) == HIGH){
  player1 = 0;
  player2 = 0;
  for (int a =0; a < 10; a  ){
    CircuitPlayground.clearPixels(); 
     delay(100);
     for (int i =0; i < 10; i  ){
       CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(i, CircuitPlayground.colorWheel(25 * i));
       CircuitPlayground.strip.show();
     }
     delay(100);
     CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
  }
  
}
  
}
```

visual after pressing left button: [image]

Comment: You should give your pins useful names and use these instead in the code, it would make it easier to understand it. Also a smaller example without the full game inside is better to figure out the problem. What should the program do instead, after pressing the left button? what is pin 19 connected to? also your initilization of your for loops seems wrong.